# Are these all phrasal verbs?

Tags: english, phrasal-verbs

Consider the following sentences

1. He **pushed open** the door.
2. He **pushed** the door **open**.

Are the two ‘**pushed open**’ phrasal verbs and have ‘the door’ as their objects?

Comment: Easy to tell. Substitute a pronoun for _the door_. _*He pushed open it._ ~ _He pushed it open._ Particle shift (which applies only to phrasal verbs) is obligatory with a pronoun object.

Comment: From your words, “pry open are phrasal verbs,” ; “pry open it” doesn’t seem to be possible. So I’m very confused why you called this phrasal verbs? [link](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103240/what-do-you-call-the-adjectives-between-transitive-verbs-and-objects)

Comment: If it is a phrasal verb, like _pry open_, then _*pry open it_ **should** be impossible, and _pry it open_ should be OK. If it's **not** a phrasal verb (like _look at_), then _look at it_ is OK, but _*look it at_ is not.

Comment: @jlawler Thank you very much. Now I understand what you say.

Comment: More phrasal verb puzzles (for native speakers -- if you're not one, find one to use as an informant) [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/EnglishPhrasalVerbs.pdf).

Comment: You were the one for me to meet English syntax. And now I’m enjoying reading it. I hope I would be better to understand what you say in the near future. Thank you.

Comment: @jlawler So you're saying it is a phrasal verb? I was not aware of the test... I thought it worked for transitive verbs only.

Comment: The rule requires a direct object, yes. So it's only one test of many; and individual phrasal verbs are just as variable in syntax as non-phrasal verbs -- i.e, extremely. That's why we need tests. Every governed rule like Particle Shift is a test for verb individuality, as the [Phrasal Verb puzzle](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/EnglishPhrasalVerbs.pdf) shows.

Comment: Ah, phrasal verbs. The English cousin of "aufstehen" and its kin, one of the most difficult roadblocking stones for students of English! Some are sooo illogical...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, *push open* is a phrasal verb and in both examples in the question, *the door* is the direct object, not an object of a preposition. The test mentioned in Jlawler's comment is indeed an easy way to identify the particle of phrasal verbs. One substitutes a definite pronoun in for the NP. If the pronoun must precede the particle, one knows that it is indeed a particle and not a preposition. Here are more examples of how the test works:

```
 a.  He walked over the mess.
 b.  He walked over it. 
 c. *He walked it over. - "over" in this case is a preposition, not a particle

 a.  We talked over the issue.
 b. *We talked over it.
 c.  We talked it over. - "over" in this case is a particle, not a preposition
```

These examples demonstrate that *over* in *walk over* is a preposition, and *over* in *talk over* is a particle, which means *talk over* is a phrasal verb. The pronoun diagnostic with further examples is used in the Wikipedia article on phrasal verbs here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrasal_verb.

A related question concerns the phenomenon of shifting that occurs with phrasal verbs. What is it about the syntactic structure that allows shifting to occur with phrasal verbs? The relevant difference across the particle of phrasal verbs and standard prepositions is that the particle and the NP object are sister constituents in the structure, whereas when a preposition is present, the NP is the dependent of the preposition. In other words, the structure is flat with phrasal verbs, whereas it is more layered when the preposition is present. Shifting is discussed in Wikipedia here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shifting_%28linguistics%29. The article includes examples involving phrasal verbs.

Comment: The alternation test only works on transitive phrasal verbs, though, for obvious reasons. That makes identifying and classifying intransitive phrasal verbs more troublesome. (Bitransitive phrasal verbs are already troublesome, since particle shift interacts with dative shift: _Pick me up another six-pack_ vs **Pick it me up/Pick me up it.*)

Comment: The test also works for intransitive phrasal verbs insofar as the object of any preposition that appears with the intransitive phrasal verb will fail the test. I agree that there is a problem when a ditransitive phrasal verb is involved, but such cases are really rare.